# Vercel Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'simple-concat' imported from /var/task/node_modules/mypackage/index.js

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, node-modules, vercel

I am new to node.js and vercel.
My project works in my local computer but when i deploy it to vercel, i get the following error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'simple-concat'
> imported from /var/task/node_modules/mypackage/index.js
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
> at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:894:9)
> at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:987:20)
> at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:12)
> at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1202:79)
> at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
> at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:842:30)
> at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
> at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
> at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } RequestId:
> 39a6c3ac-c643-4323-83b4-2ed45ad1920e Error: Runtime exited with error:
> exit status 1 Runtime.ExitError

I tried changing the import there to import concat from 'simple-concat/index.js'

I tried to add environment variables VERCEL_CLI_VERSION with value `vercel@28.10.2`

I tried redeploying

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few things to try:

1. Make sure the package `simple-concat` is listed in your `package.json` file as a dependency.
2. Run `npm install` or `yarn install` to install all dependencies locally before you deploy to Vercel. This makes sure that all of your required packages are in the `node_modules` directory.
3. If `simple-concat` is a native node.js module, make sure it's in the `engines` section of your `package.json` file. this is important! - it will ensure that the correct version of Node.js is used when the code is being run on Vercel.